# GeoServer with SQL Table having lat/long

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, kml, latitude-longitude

I have a table in SQL Server with geometry column.

I save geometry like : `geometry::Point(@Lat, @Long, 4326)`and this results the geometry for the given lat/long.

Now when I publish this layer in GeoServer with Declared SRS :EPSG:4326 and download the KML. It does place the point at right place on Google Earth and the layer does not render at right place in Open Layers as well.

What is wrong?

Comment: Your `geometry` Point constructor should be (longitude, latitude)

Comment: Thanks ! This made the points available at right place in google earth using KML .. but why ? msdn says to use lat/long : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type ... But, The points are still not visible in openlayers.

Comment: I have a function in angular which has been showing the layers from an array properly except this layer.

Comment: The `geography` constructor is {lat,lon}, but the `geometry` constructor is {X,Y}.

Comment: For such table is there any other specific way to consume in openlayers. Currently in openlayers I pass :- url,Format,Layers in TileWms object. It shows all layers except this table layers.

Comment: Please ask your question (just one) in the body of the Question. I won't be answering OpenLayers questions.

Comment: It would help a great deal if you would add relevant part of your OpenLayers code to your question.